# Normalizing constant & rejection sampling

Tags: self-study, density-function, rejection-sampling

I think I understand what a normalizing constant is. Say for example you have a pdf $f(x)$ with support $0 \le x \le 5$. If you wanted to truncate the pdf and only look at $0 \le x \le 3$ you would need to use a normalizing constant $c$ such that $\int_0^3 cf(x)\,dx = 1$.

The problem I'm dealing with states:

> In class we gave a rejection method for the case when the target distribution π(x)
>   is only known up to a normalizing constant. Show that the accepted samples from that
>   algorithm indeed follow the target distribution π(x)

What does it mean when it says we only know the target distribution up to a normalizing constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re: What does it mean when it says we only know the target distribution [π(x)] up to a normalizing constant?

This means that π(x) is *proportional to* the p.d.f. for every value x. That is, if f(x) is the p.d.f., then there is some constant K such that

f(x) = K * π(x)

for all values of x.